# How to install pdo_mysql driver on OSX Catalina?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I ran a script that uses PDO, I received an error from the console:

```
Can't connect to database: could not find driver
```

After which I read that I need to uncomment the line with pdo_mysql in php.ini. Unfortunately, this led to the following error now popping up in me:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql'
```

PHP set through brew install php@7.2

I tried to install via pecl, but it produces:

```
running: make INSTALL_ROOT="/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-artemsokoloviZ2ILB/install-
PDO-1.0.3" install
Installing shared extensions:     /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-artemsokoloviZ2ILB/install-PDO-1.0.3/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.31_1/pecl/20170718/
cp: modules/*: No such file or directory
make: *** [install-modules] Error 1
ERROR: `make INSTALL_ROOT="/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-artemsokoloviZ2ILB/install-PDO-1.0.3" install' failed
```